# FCM Web push notification Google Analytics

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In our web application, we use FCM to send push notifications. Tell me, please, is there a way to track using Google Analytics getting and opening push by the user?

All solutions that I found on the Internet are applicable only to mobile applications.

Thanks so much for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase only tracks events for iOS and Android users. It does not track events for web users, so you won't be able to see how many web users have opened your FCM messages.

The best workaround I know if is to use regular Google Analytics in your web app, and then combine the two data streams with either Google Tag Manager, or within BigQuery.